# gnuplot - putting fractions into axis label

Tags: plot, format, gnuplot, axis, axis-labels

I have a log-log plot, counting in powers of 2 up from 1/32.

How can I make the axis labels < 1 be displayed as fractions, rather than decimals (e.g. 1/32 instead of 0.03125)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to label the tics individually by hand:

```
set xtics ("1/2" .5, "1/4" 0.25, "1/8" .125, ...)
```

or automatically:

```
set logsc x; set xr [1./32:1]
set xtics ("1",1) # remove all tics and set one initial tic
do for [i=1:5] {set xtics add (sprintf("1/%.f",2**i) 1./2**i)}
plot x
```